# CNN predictions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, prediction

I have built and trained a model with Keras using both a training and validation sets.
I would like to make predictions on unlabelled data, I have one folder containing 300 images of dogs, cats and horses. In the predictions I get the probabilities for each class.

How to I get a final output that tells / shows me how many of those 300 images belong to each class?

I upload the model

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model')
```

I then reformat the testing images

```
test_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'test_images',
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=10,
    classes = None,
    class_mode= None)
```

and then I finally make a prediction

```
predictions = new_model.predict(test_batches, steps=30, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import collections, numpy
collections.Counter(np.argmax(predictions, axis = 1))
```

Comment: anyway for it to display the name of the class not the number?

Comment: The labels are one hot encoded so you can check which display belongs to which class. For example Cat [1, 0, 0], dog [0, 1, 0] and horse [0, 0, 1] and so In the output of the code I wrote above, number 0 represents cat, number 1 dog, number 2 horse.